# How to filter a list of string from HTML using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

people, I want to print the list of string which is after comma.

```
userName = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class=\'linkedAccountUserName\']')
for i in range(len(userName)):
  print(userName[i].text)
```

above is my code

Output:

```
My Preferences
Linked Accounts
Ram, Tulasi
Worker | BACG
Ar, Raj
Worker | BACG
Pany, Venkat
Worker | BACG
Sarah Isaacmoon, Joyce
Worker | BACG
Kumar, Akshay
Worker | BACG
Sridharan, Akil
Worker | BACG
Sign Out
```

Expected Output:

```
Tulasi
Raj
Venkat
Joyce
Akshay
Akil
```

Comment: provide your link or DOM ?

Comment: Is there any way to filter in code itself

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below solution ::

```
txt= userName[i].text
x = txt.split(",",1)[1]
print("Result after first split ::: ", x)
txt1= x.split(" ", 2)
print("Result after second split :::", txt1)
x = txt1[1]
print("Final Result :::", x)
```

[image]